# Select cells(Ctrl+A) then Copy range and paste to another sheet's first empty row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to copy a range from a sheet to another sheet's first empty row. But instead of copying the whole spreadseet i want to select the cells (like i do with CTRL+ A) and only the selected(ctrl+A) cells should be copied to another sheet's first row. Here is a script that i found here in stackoverflow and it  works but it only copy that range i give for example: sheet1!F1:H3. I want the script to find the cells like ctrl+ A does and then it copies to the other sheet's first empty row.

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

Here is the script:

```
function moveValuesOnly () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ();
  var source = ss.getRange ("Sheet1!F1:H3");
  var destSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  // Déterminer l'emplacement de la première ligne vide.
  var destRange = destSheet.getRange(destSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);`enter code here`
  source.copyTo (destRange, {contentsOnly: true});
  source.clear ();
}
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, do you mean duplicating the sheet? Or just copying the data from one sheet and paste it to the other sheet from cell A1. See [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)

Comment: Have you searched the documentation? Have you tried recording a macro? See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: I want to copy the data from one sheet and paste it to the other sheet. Lets say there is Sheet1 and Sheet2.  And I wanna copy the data from sheet1 to sheet2. But once Sheet1 has 200 row, i copy it to sheet2 but next time Sheet1 has 400 row.  So i want excel to realize the current actual amount of data in sheet1 and copy it with the script to Sheet2 first empty row so i can collect data continously to sheet2.

In other words,  Sheet1 has 200 rows it copies the 200 rows to sheet2 after i update the data in sheet1, it will have 400 row. The script copy again this 400 row to sheet 201 th row.

Comment: If it is still not clear i can try to explain more. Let me know if you guys understand it and thank you for your help in advance. @kessy

Comment: Kessy already gave you the answer. Have you looked into the link provided by kess?

Comment: The OP wants to imitate the behavior of selecting the minimal rectangular range which contains only cells with stuff in them, not all rows/columns. Does `Sheet.getDataRange()` select the same cells you observe when you type Ctrl-A?

Comment: `Range.getDataRegion()` does. Op could've just searched ctrl+A in the documentation.

Comment: Can you update on your progress? Have you tried anything else?

Comment: Yes it is completely working with getDataRange(). Thank you for the help. I really appreciate it. You guys are the best. :)

Answer (score 0):

Using [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange) solved the issue.

As mentioned in the documentation:

> Returns a Range corresponding to the dimensions in which data is present.

Comment: Why is this community wiki? Weren't you the one who answered in the comments?